# Prism for Xamarin.Forms: Failing to remove page from navigation stack

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a situation which I believe is just like the example Brian Lagunas discusses in a [blog post](https://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-in-prism-for-xamarin-forms-7-0/) under the heading, "Remove Pages from Navigation stack":

1. User is on ViewA, and taps a button to navigate to ViewB.
2. On ViewB, the user taps a button to navigate to ViewC.
3. If/when the user taps the back arrow on ViewC, I would like it to navigate back to ViewA immediately, rather than first having to go to ViewB.

When navigating to ViewC, my call to `NavigateAsync("ViewC")` gets a success status in its NavigationResult. However, if I try removing ViewB from the stack using `NavigateAsync("../ViewC")` it results in a failed navigation status.

The app still navigates to ViewC, but ViewB is not removed from the stack, so tapping the back arrow on ViewC still navigates back to ViewB, and then you can tap the back arrow there to navigate back to ViewA.

The NavigationResult contains a NullReferenceException:

```
    Non-public members: 
    Exception: {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.RemovePagesFromNavigationPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page currentPage, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] pagesToRemove) [0x0001d] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:452 
  at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.RemoveAndPush (Xamarin.Forms.Page currentPage, System.String nextSegment, System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T] segments, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated) [0x00136] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:444 
  at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.ProcessNavigation (Xamarin.Forms.Page currentPage, System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1[T] segments, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated) [0x000b4] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:353 
  at Prism.Navigation.PageNavigationService.NavigateInternal (System.Uri uri, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated) [0x000f9] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Navigation\PageNavigationService.cs:322 }
    Success: false
```

None of this navigation is modal, and there are no tabbed pages involved. I tried making a call to `GetNavigationUriPath()` just before making the `NavigateAsync` call to go to ViewC, and I believe it looked correct: `/NavigationPage/ViewA/ViewB`

Does anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?
I'm using Prism.DryIoc.Forms 7.2.0.1422, Prism.Plugin.Popups, and Xamarin.Forms 4.7.0.968.

Comment: Could you provide the xaml with code for me to reproduce?

Comment: Thank you, @WendyZang-MSFT. That's where it gets tricky... What I'm hoping to learn is how to troubleshoot the navigation service to find out why I'm getting a NullReferenceException. I don't think something is wrong with Prism or Xamarin.Forms. I'm fairly sure the error is mine. I created a small repro project, where the navigation works exactly as it should: https://github.com/jbachelor/XFPrismSample

Comment: I guess it's specifical navigation of Prism. We could check it.

Comment: Thank you so much, @WendyZang-MSFT... I appreciate it! I've actually been bugging Dan Siegel (one of the maintainers of Prism) about this issue, and he's been super helpful. I'll update this post if/when we find the root of the issue.

Comment: There is an [existing issue](https://github.com/dansiegel/Prism.Plugin.Popups/issues/166) that *might* share the same root cause as the one I'm running into. Essentially, my issue appears to be caused by going straight from showing a popup, and then immediately navigating. Adding a brief delay to allow the popup time to clear out and then making the navigation call avoids the issue. I'll be adding details and a repro app there soon.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. We would follow the issue.